# How to loop folder and subfolder directory creation?

Tags: batch-file, directory

I'm trying to create a batch that will setup a directory with a set of folders, that will then each all get the a set of subfolders. So at the end you would have something like A1\B1, A1\B2, A2\B1, and A2\B2. I can't seem to get the subfolders to create within the main folders.

```
set A1=Level1
set A2=Level2

set B1="00 General"
set B2="01 Civil"

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set A') do md %%s

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set B') do (md %A%\%B%) %%s

pause
```

Am I nesting something improperly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't nest at all.

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set A') do ( 
  for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('set B') do md "%%a\%%b
)
```

`md` is able to create "dir/subdir/subdir"

I suggest, changing your variablenames. There are systemvariables `appdata` and `allusersprofile`. I would name them `#A1`, `#A2`, `#B1` and `#B2`

But it's easier to work without variables at all:

```
for %%a in (Level1 Level2) do (
  for %%b in ("00 General" "01 Civil") do md "%%a\%%~b"
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that works beautifully. The initial thought with the variables is that they could be easily changed if they were all listed and defined at the beginning, purely from an organizational/visual standpoint. Working without them tho is much easier, thanks!